# round off a Date to the end of day

Tags: java, android, date

I want the get the End of day for a particular date .

Example: **"Tue Mar 02 00:00:00 GMT+08:00 2021"**

How can I get the End of day for the above date???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the last moment of a day is problematic because of the infinitely divisible last second.

Generally better to work with half-open approach where the beginning to a span of time is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.

So a day starts at the first moment of the day and runs up to, but does not include, the first moment of the following day.

```
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofHours( 8 ) ;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.of( 2021 , Month.MARCH , 2 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , offset ) ;
OffsetDateTime odtFirstMomentDayAfter = odt.toLocalDate().plusDays(1).atStartOfDay( offset ).toOffsetDateTime() ;
```

By the way, when adding and subtracting time, you should be using time zones rather than mere offsets, and using `ZonedDateTime` rather than `OffsetDateTime`. In your particular time zone, the politicians may have declared a change to the offset during the span of time being added/subtracted.